# Generator of the joint process $(X_t,Y_t)$ where $Y_t= e^{-t}W(e^{2t})$ and $X_t = \int^t_0 Y_sds$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion and let

$$ Y_t := e^{-t}W(e^{2t}), \qquad X_t := \int^t_0 Y_s ds $$

Show that the joint process $(X_t,Y_t)$ is Markovian and find the generator of the process.

This is an exercise that I came across while reading a book. I can show the first part where the joint process is indeed Markovian. However, I don't know how to find the generator

$$ L[f](0,x) := \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{E_{(0,x)}[f(X_t,Y_t)] -f(0,x)}{t}. $$

for $f$ sufficiently regular.

My first thought is to use Ito, but I only know the form of $f(t,X_t)=...$ not the form $f(X_t,Y_t)=...$ (if there is any) and my second thought is to use the joint density but don't know how to proceed to find the joint density for now.

Answer (score 5):

To find the generator I will look for the two-dimensional SDE that is solved
by $(X_t,Y_t)\,.$

- It is not hard to see that
  $$\tag{1}
  B_t:=\int_0^te^{-s}\,dW_{e^{2s}}
  $$
  is a continuous martingale with quadratic variation $t\,.$ Therefore is is a
  Brownian motion that satisfies
  $$\tag{2}
  Y_t=e^{-t}\,W_{e^{2t}}=e^{-t}\int_0^te^u\,dB_u=\int_0^te^{u-t}\,dB_u\,.
  $$
- It is easy to see that the SDE that is solved by $Y_t$ is the one
  of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:
  $$\tag{3}
  dY_t=-Y_t\,dt+dB_t\,.
  $$
  By definition,
  $$\tag{4}
  dX_t=Y_t\,dt\,.
  $$
  The system we were looking for is (3) and (4).
- This can be written in matrix/vector form as
  $$\tag{6}
  d\mathbf{Z}_t=\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&1\\0&-1}}_{\textstyle=:\mathbf{b}}\,\mathbf{Z}_t\;dt+\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}}_{\textstyle=:\boldsymbol{\sigma}}\,d\mathbf{B}_t
  $$
  where
  $$\tag{7}
  \mathbf{Z}_t=\pmatrix{X_t\\Y_t}\,,\quad \mathbf{B}_t=\pmatrix{B_t\\C_t}
  $$
  and $C_t$ is a dummy Brownian motion independent of $B\,.$
- Since
  $$\tag{8}
  \boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\sigma}^\top=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}=:\mathbf{a}
  $$
  the generator of the Markov process $(X_t,Y_t)$ is
  $$\tag{9}
  A=\left(\mathbf{b}{x\choose y}\right)\cdot\nabla+\frac12\nabla^\top\mathbf{a}\nabla=y\,\partial_x-y\,\partial_y+\frac12\partial_y^2\,.
  $$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have 2 questions. What is the dot $\cdot$ in (6) after you define $b$? Can you elaborate more why $(-X_t,Y_t)$ has a nicer generator? I don't see what the difference is when we replace $-X_t$ by the original $X_t$ in the definition of $Z_t$ above?

Comment: @JeffreyJao There were still issues that I hopefully fixed now. In short: the drift $\mathbb{b}$ must be a matrix because in this case it is a linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2\,.$ This also resolves the puzzle I had with $(X_t,Y_t)$ vs $(-X_t,Y_t)\,.$ Thanks for reading carefully.

Comment: Thanks too, but I believe the last line should be $y \partial_x - y\partial_y$ :)

Comment: @JeffreyJao yep.